# Why didn't the fog enter the supermarket in The Mist?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mist

In [*The Mist* (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0884328/), a white fog covers a small town, and a number of residents take refuge in the local supermarket.  But the fog stops at the glass windows, never seeping through the cracks around the doors, or later in the movie, through the broken windows or the opened garage door. Why?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that the mist *did* come in a bit when the windows broke, just not as a big, rolling fog, but rather as a thin veil that was dispersed by the AC. I’d have to check again, but I’m sure the color palette of the scene got a little faded once the windows broke. As for the loading-dock door, if I remember correctly, I think it did indeed seem like there was a barrier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going to speculate that it's because the fog was not necessarily supernatural in nature and the supermarket had a climate control system.

Buildings in San Francisco don't get filled with fog even if they're surrounded by it.

Comment: The source of the monsters was never really answered definitively, only speculations about scientific experiments and such, but even then, it was not really supernatural, just alien. So I agree that there was nothing special, intelligent, or alive about the mist itself (I think the same can be said about the fog in *The Fog* as well). I can completely imagine and even *feel* the chill in the supermarket due to its air-conditioning, which of course would make the windows and air cold, causing molecules of water vapor cold and thus to condense outside instead of seeping in and staying aloft.